# Synchronize Data with Async functions

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking, semaphore

I have a Async Interface to some external Hardware which allows Reading and Writing values.

Let's assume it looks like this:

```
interface IAsyncConnection
{
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string,object> ReadAsync(IReadOnlyList<string> keysToRead)
    void WriteAsync(IReadOnlyDictionary<string,object> values) 
}
```

The Hardware and the Protocol itself are thread safe, so if i call `ReadAsync`and `WriteAsync` at the same moment one of the two methods obtains a lock and executes first while the other method just takes a bit longer.

As the Protocol does not support change notification I have implemented some kind of a polling loop:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<string,object> oldValues = null;
while(true)
{
    Task minimumTime = Task.Delay(100);
    var newValues = await this.connection.ReadAsync(valuesToRead);
    var changedValues = this.GetChangedValues(newVales, oldValues)

    this.Update(changedValues); //Actually delegates ViewModel changes and updates the UI
    await minimumTime; //just some sample
}
```

Now I run into trouble if I call write in the moment the Polling loop is inside `GetChangedValues` because the Update method gets called with old values which does set the UI back to the old value before writing (which causes further problems in Undo/Redo stack etc.)

Now if the Read would be synchron I would just extend the Connection with a `SyncRoot` Property which I could lock. And create some synchronization between objects written and updated to get the current changed values properly.

How can I achive something similar with async Methods ?

EDIT:
To clarify, a `SemaphoreSlim` SyncRoot does not support reentrance (how should it, ofc) which means if I create some kind of locking inside the `IAsyncConnection` and make it available external via a Property, than i cannot call WaitAsync in the `PollingLoop` class and inside the `IAsyncConnection` because this would reenter the `SemaphoreSlim`. I can of course implement it in a way where the WriteAsync method of the Connection obtains the `SemaphoreSlim` and the `PollingLoop` obtains the `SemaphoreSlim`. But this seems like some kind of magical (unmaintainable) synchronization as the real Connection has about 12 Methods which do not run at the same time.

Comment: My suggestion would be to post more code and explain the locking scheme more clearly. My hunch is that you need to clean up the locking scheme conceptually. There's no API fix possible which is why I deleted the answer. Reentrancy as a general rule points to bad design.

Comment: Can you explain why reentrance is bad design.

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html It's not a hard rule but as you can see it tends to cause problems.

Comment: Strange never faced any of the problems, however i will try to change the design to non-recursive locks, and see if that gets stuff going..

Answer (score 0):

What you need, I think, is two independent tasks - one for polling the hardware (protocol) at 100ms intervals that pushes data (if any) onto a BlockingCollection, and a second tasks that reads data from the BlockingCollection when new data actually arrives.

Then, calculate the changed values in the seconds task that reads from the BlockingCollection.

The advantage with the BlockingCollection is that you can do something like:

```
_queue = new BlockingCollection<KeyValuePair<string,object>>();
// The poll task does pure protocol-polling
// I assume that a read with no hardware data returns empty
// IEnumerable of KeyValuePair (immediately)
// You can have it async but thats because of the IO-operation, not
// Because you're waiting for data. The polltask does what you want
_pollTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var newValues = this.connection.Read(valuesToRead);
        foreach(var newValue in newValues)
        {
            // Next, I try to add new data and wait max 1 second
            // if the queue is full to wait for the second task to read
            if(!_queue.TryAdd(newValue, 1000, token))
            {
                 if(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                 {
                     // Log that queue was full
                 }
            }
        }
        token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(100); // Sleeps 100ms    
    }
}

//
// The read task blocks forever (at TryTake) if no data exists (has been written
// by the poll-task), and executes check for changed values and updates
// the gui if, and only if, new data actually exists
_readTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, object> nextItem;
        if(_queue.TryTake(out nextItem, Timeout.Infinite, token))
        {
            if(!token.IsCancellationRequested && this.ValueChanged(nextItem, oldValues) 
            {
                 this.Update(nextItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```